# Can't restart Liferay: numerous BeanCreationException-s

Tags: spring, exception, tomcat, liferay

After restarting a long-worked Liferay I got a numerous exceptions during startup (approx 93 chained exceptions) with out-of-memory at the end.

No exception looks like because of my portlet development. Probably some configuration error or something.

What can be a reason?

Message below:

```
15:34:45,286 ERROR [ContextLoader:227] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ResourceActions' defined in class path resource [META-INF/util-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortletLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AccountLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AccountService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AddressLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.AddressService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.BrowserTrackerLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ClassNameLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ClassNameService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ClusterGroupLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CMISRepositoryLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CompanyService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ContactLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ContactService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.CountryService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.EmailAddressLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.EmailAddressService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.GroupService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ImageLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ImageService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/staging-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutBranchLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutBranchService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutPrototypeLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutPrototypeService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutRevisionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutRevisionService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetBranchLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetBranchService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetPrototypeLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetPrototypeService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutTemplateLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ListTypeService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.LockLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.MembershipRequestLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.MembershipRequestService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.OrganizationLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.OrganizationService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.OrgLaborLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.OrgLaborService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PasswordPolicyLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PasswordPolicyService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PasswordPolicyRelLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PasswordTrackerLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PermissionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PermissionService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PhoneLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PhoneService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PluginSettingLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PluginSettingService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortalLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortalPreferencesLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortletService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortletItemLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortletPreferencesLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortletPreferencesLocalServiceStagingAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/staging-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.PortletPreferencesService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.QuartzLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.RegionService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.RepositoryLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.RepositoryService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.RepositoryEntryLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceActionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceBlockLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceBlockService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceBlockPermissionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceCodeLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourcePermissionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourcePermissionService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ResourceTypePermissionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.RoleService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceComponentLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ShardLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.SubscriptionLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.TeamLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.TeamService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ThemeLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.ThemeService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.TicketLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.service.UserService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/portal-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.mail.service.MailService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/mail-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase your permGen Space.

**liferay/tomcat/bin/** open **setenv.bat** for windows or **setenv.sh** for linux Operating system.

find this paratmeter **-XX:MaxPermSize** increase size of this parameter.

i.e

```
 set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=500m"
```

Comment: while you're at it you might want to change from JAVA_OPTS to CATALINA_OPTS (more info here: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-26464)